# Compilation error with simple helloworld.c program with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, debian

When I tried to compile my helloworld.c with

> gcc helloworld.c -v -o myhelloworld

I have the following error :

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 8.3.0-6' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-8 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'hellosqd' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu helloworld.c -quiet -dumpbase helloworld.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase helloworld -version -o /tmp/cc0TkZSM.s
gcc: internal compiler error: Erreur de segmentation signal terminated program cc1
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

My source program is a simple helloworld.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

My host is a Debian Buster based on amd64. And gcc version is (dpkg -l | grep gcc):

```
ii  gcc                                   4:8.3.0-1                                    amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-8                                 8.3.0-6                                      amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-8-base:amd64                      8.3.0-6                                      amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libgcc-8-dev:amd64                    8.3.0-6                                      amd64        GCC support library (development files)
ii  libgcc1:amd64                         1:8.3.0-6                                    amd64        GCC support library
```

I tried to reinstall build-essential, but not worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A segmentation fault during compilation is very likely a bug somewhere in the toolchain. The instructions in the error message to submit a bug report sound like a good idea (preceded by looking for an existing bug report that fits). It's possibly caused by the combination of parameters that was passed to cc1 - try to find a minimum subset of those parameters that causes the segmentation fault - it'll help greatly in analyzing the cause.

Comment: Thanks to your reply. I'll try to find the paramaters thats cause the segmentation fault.